# Cutting a raster into a parallelogram

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a question about the shape of the raster to be cut out. If you specify a range in raster extraction and select crop, it will be cropped into a rectangular shape.
I want to cut out a parallelogram instead of a rectangle. Is this possible?
We know the coordinates of the four corners of the parallelogram.

Answer (score 3):

No, a raster will always be stored as a rectangular matrix. What is possible, however, is to set the values of the raster out of the parallelogram to "NoData" (using [clip](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction/cliprasterbymasklayer.html)). Compression algorithm will then reduce the size of your raster and it will "look" as if it had been cropped by a parallelogram if the NoData is displayed as transparent (which is the case by default).